# How should I do this (Game)?

Tags: ios, logistics

Right now I have coded about 80% of my game and the remaining 20% is the actual game part of it. I need to know how I should go upon actually making the game part. 
Pretty much it will be somewhat similar to Doodle Jump. There will be gravity, the accelerometer, and a spawn system for platforms. I need to know if I should use UIKit or Cocos2D for this.

I know I can do gravity and use the accelerometer easily using UIKit but I am worried about the platform part. My 'Doodle Jump character' is not a regular square or rectangle so should I just crop it as best I can? The reason I am worried is because say the character falls on a platform, so his body could be a little off since CGRectIntersectsRect does not have pixel collision detection, so do you think it is fine the way it is?

If you need more info or aren't sure what I am trying to do, just let me know. In the end I just need to know if I should use Cocos2D or UIKit. 
Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: For the most part, you shouldn't need to worry about pixel collision.

Comment: so your saying I can do this via UIKit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer would be that, while you may be able to develop the game in UIKit, my suspiction is that it will be better in the long run to do it in Cocos2D.  Not only will you have tools which are better for doing stuff like collision detection, you can also use a Physics Engine to handle the gravity and things like that.  Basically, Cocos2d was made to do exactly the kinds of things you want to do, and UIKit wasn't...it was made for user interfaces.

Still, the collision detection you do will, mostly likely, not need to be down the level of individual pixels.  One rectangle might be enough, or perhaps you can use several to get more accuracy.  So can you pull it off in UIKit...maybe, but I bet your game will turnout better overall if you use Cocos2d.